# Bitwise operations and setting "flags"

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift, bitwise-and, bitwise-or

So this is an update to my last post, but I'm still having a lot of trouble understanding how this works. So I was giving the main function:

```
void set_flag(int* flag_holder, int flag_position);
int check_flag(int flag_holder, int flag_position);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int flag_holder = 0;
    int i;
    set_flag(&flag_holder, 3);
    set_flag(&flag_holder, 16);
    set_flag(&flag_holder, 31);
    for(i = 31; i >= 0; i--) {
        printf("%d", check_flag(flag_holder, i));
        if(i % 4 == 0)
            printf(" ");
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

And for the assignment we are supposed to write the functions set_flag and check_flag, so that the output is equal to:

```
1000 0000 0000 0001 0000 0000 0000 1000
```

So from what I understand, were supposed to use the "set_flag" function to make sure that the nth bit is 1. And the "check_flag" function returns an integer that is 0 when the nth bit is 0, and 1 when it is 1. I don't understand what "set_flag" is really doing, and how 3, 16, and 31, will be saved as "flags" which then return as 1's in "check_flag".

Comment: What have you tried and where are you failing? Please read  [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

When working with binary or hexadecimal values a common approach is the define a mask that we will apply to a main value.

You can easily set one or more bits to '1' with the inclusive OR operator '|'

eg: we want to set the bit#0 to '1'

```
main value  01011000 | 
mask        00000001 = 
result      01011001
```

To test a particular bit you can use the AND operator '&'

eg: we want to test the bit#3

```
main value  01011000 & 
mask        00001000 = 
result      00001000
```

note: you may need to properly format result; here the & operation will return either zero or non-zero (but nor necessary '1').

So here are the 2 functions set_flag and check_flag:

```
void set_flag(int* flag_holder, int flag_position) {
    int mask =  1 << flag_position;  
    flag_holder = flag_holder | mask;
}

int check_flag(int flag_holder, int flag_position) {
    int mask =  1 << flag_position;
    int check = flag_holder & mask;  
    return (check !=0 ? 1 : 0);
}
```

In these scenarios we need a binary mask to set/check only one bit. The code "int mask = 1 << flag_position;" builds this single bit mask, it basically sets the bit#0 to '1' then shift to the left to the #bit we want to set/check.

Answer (score 0):

Function Set_flag and Function Check_flag:

```
void set_flag(int* flag_holder, int flag_position) {
    int mask =  1 << flag_position;  
    *flag_holder = *flag_holder | mask;
}

int check_flag(int flag_holder, int flag_position) {
    int mask =  1 << flag_position;
    int check = flag_holder & mask;  

   return (check !=0 ? 1 : 0);
}
```

Run it along with the main program and you will get the desired output.